# getting visible radi button jquery

Tags: jquery

I have aform which has lots of radio button both visible and hidden. I need to get only the visible radio buttons and do some manipulations. I am trying the below code. But its not working. Can somebody please help me in this.
One group has 4-5 radio buttons. I need to check any of the radio button in the group is checked or not. I have the code which does just the opposite.
I need something like this

```
$(group).find(':radio:visible:not(:checked)').each(function() {...});
```

But this is giving some error.

I have a fiddle created. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/45/

Actually I need to see if any of the radio button is checked or not. If nothing is selected it should display error and return false. If both the radio groups are selected it should return true.
But the fiddle is acting just the opposite. I tried make the fiddle with the above code. But its not working correctly. Can somebody please correct the fiddle?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var returnVal = true;
    $.each($('.input-container:visible[data-validation=required]'), function (idx,group) {
        var checked = $(group).find(':radio:checked');            
        $(group).next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
        if (!checked.length) {
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            $(group).after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');
            returnVal = false;
        }
    });
    alert(returnVal);
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/51/

Elaboration: I changed the logic to do what you actually seem to want to do: for each visible group, see if a radio button is checked. If not, show a text (which is now specified on the group tag, not on the individual radio button) and return false.

Comment: Hi Hans..Can I do something like this validation for dropdowns also? Actually my dropdown is styled using selectmenu. So do I need to use any separate attributes/properties for that?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I wonder if you're really doing yourself a favor by trying to do everything by hand. If I were you, I'd look into an existing validation library. You'll have way more work doing validation manually for every field in your application, than you'll have if you pick another validation library and learn to use it so it does what you want it to do.

Since you already use jQuery, you could use a jQuery plugin for validation, such as http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: Ok..I tried to do for dropdowns as well..But as i told this drodpown is styled using selectmenu, I am having a difficult time trying to get selected value and displaying it. Also I am not able to get only the visible selectmenu in thr form using :visible attribute. If I use :visible, the control is not even going inside the loop..Any idea how we can handle to get only visible selectmenu?

Comment: I don't know what selectmenu is, so at the very least I need to see some relevant code in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
$(group).find(":radio:visible").not(":checked")
```